# Incomparable types

Tags: android, android-fragment

Имеется участок кода:

```
private void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                fragment = new PizzaFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new PastaFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new StoresFragment();
                break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TopFragment();
        }

    }
```

По непонятной причине подчеркивает строку `fragment = new PastaFragment();` и пишет

> Incomparable types. Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Found:
>   asus.example.com.notes1.PastaFragment

, хотя PastaFragment практически одинаковый с остальными фрагментами, на которые Android Studio не ругается.

Код PastaFragment:

```
package asus.example.com.notes1;


    import android.app.ListFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class PastaFragment extends ListFragment {


        public PastaFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pastas));
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pasta, container, false);
        }

    }
```

А вот, например, код PizzaFragment:

```
package asus.example.com.notes1;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class PizzaFragment extends ListFragment {


    public PizzaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pizzas));
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, container, false);
    }

}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: В `PastaFragment` замените `import android.app.ListFragment;` на `import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;` они не взаимозаменяемы. Фрагменты рекомендуется использовать только из `support-library`

Comment: @woesss, думаю, это можно и в ответ написать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как скажете). Я был уверен, что найдётся дубликат с готовым ответом - проблема точно уже не раз фигурировала.

Comment: @woesss, да, проблема не нова, но вот лично мне с ходу не удалось найти подходящий вопрос-дубликат)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PastaFragment замените

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

на

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

они не взаимозаменяемы.
Фрагменты рекомендуется использовать только из `support-library`